# Cannot find libc headers in MSYS2

Tags: msys2

I'm trying to build GNU Make in MSYS2 using Mingw-W64 but Make fails because pwd.h is missing. What package provides this?

Comment: I found it in msys2-runtime-devel but it doesn't seem to work with Mingw-w64 compilers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MSYS2 has build environment in this case might not be appropriate. MSYS2 has no facility to deal with unix user accounts and passwords for now. If looking for `getpwnam()` and friends, using Cygwin may be able to help you get there.